# Including and excluding helpers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

To include a Rails helper, helper :helper_name and to include all helpers, helper :all is specified in the application_controller.

Now, how to include say N-1 of the available helpers? In other words, how to exclude a very few helpers?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this? Rails has defaulted to `helper :all` for a while now.

Comment: @John: Correct, the helper :all is more than enough for most applications. Just that, I would love to know if include/exclude is possible like I mentioned in the question. This came up as part of my fiddling around with the application by changing default settings :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would need to write a custom method (say, `all_helpers`) to get symbols (`:foo`) or module names (`FooHelper`) for all of your helpers (probably via file system calls to the `app/helpers` directory) and then allow an exclusion list to be passed to the method. Then call it something like:

```
helper all_helpers(:exclude => :bar)
```

Take a look at Rails' `ActionController::Helpers#all_application_helpers` method for details on how to pull helper names from the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I would have thought that Rails would have a built-in method for this. I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Stex/9528784) for an initializer if someone might need it as well